# Sybase Select WHERE IN given order

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by, sybase, sap-ase

Is there a way to keep the order when using SELECT WHERE IN() in Sybase

There are two examples in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (118,17,113,23,72) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id,118,17,113,23,72)


SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (118,17,113,23,72) 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '118,17,113,23,72')
```

I need it in Sybase Ase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break down the argument list with a `case` statement the explicitly assigns an ascending counter to the arguments and order according to that:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     sometable 
WHERE    id IN (118,17,113,23,72) 
ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 118 THEN 1
                 WHEN 17  THEN 2
                 WHEN 113 THEN 3
                 WHEN 23  THEN 4
                 WHEN 72  THEN 5
          END ASC
```

It's clunky as hell, but it should work.